# Poisson Distribution Problem relating to birthdays

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, birthday

Consider a random collection of n individuals. When approximating the probability that no 3 of these individuals share the same birthday, a better Poisson approximation than that obtained in the text (at least for values of n between 80 and 90) is obtained by letting $E_i$ be the event that there are at least 3 birthdays on day i, i=1,......,365.

(a) Find P($E_i$).

(b) Give an approximation for the probability that no three individuals share the same birthday.

(c) Evaluate the preceding when n=88 (which can beshown to be the smallest value of n for which theprobability exceeds 0.5).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The poisson-distribution is a well approximation of the binomial distribution, if $n$ is large and $p$ is small. The parameter $\lambda$ is
$\lambda=np$ in the approximation.

Comment: So for n, would i just leave it as n since n can be between 80 and 90.. and for p would it be $(\frac{1}{365})^x$ where x is the number of people with the same birthday?

Comment: Not quite, we have $p=\frac{1}{365}$ here and ask for the probability that we have at least $3$ successes. It is better to calculate $1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$

Comment: Yes that was my thought here as well, so would n = 1, 2, or 0 here then?

Comment: As I understood the qeustion, the number of persons is $80$ to $90$. So, $n$ is in the same range. $k$ has to be at least $3$.

Comment: The exact value for $P(X=0)$ is $(\frac{364}{365})^n$, the approximated is $exp(-\frac{n}{365})$

Comment: so then what is P(X = 1) ..?

Comment: The binomial distribution gives $\frac{n}{365}(\frac{364}{365})^{n-1}$, the approximation is $exp(\frac{-n}{365})\times \frac{n}{365}$

Comment: Finally, for $X=2$, we have $\binom{n}{2}(\frac{1}{365})^2(\frac{364}{365})^{n-2}$ and the approximation $exp(\frac{-n}{365})(\frac{n}{365})^2\times \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: So for X=1, its $n (\frac{1}{365})^1 (\frac{364}{365})^{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.